# FullSimplify yields different output with exact and decimal input

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-test

I'm trying to define a predicate function to identify if the expression is a geometric sequence. This is the function I came up with so far:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
geometricSequenceQ[expr_, var_] := Module[{a}, a = (expr /. var -> #) &;
If[FullSimplify[a[1]*(a[2]/a[1])^(var - 1) == a[var],
Assumptions -> var \[Element] Integers && var > 0], True, False]]
```

But it doesn't seem to work correctly with inputs involving decimals:

```
In[5]:= geometricSequenceQ[(-1/2)^(5 n), n]
Out[5]= True
```

(-1/2)^(5 n) is indeed a geometric sequence with the common ratio of (-1/32). However:

```
In[6]:= geometricSequenceQ[(-0.5)^(5 n), n]
Out[6]= If[(-0.5)^(5 n) == (-0.03125)^n, True, False]
```

Why is the result different for exact and decimal inputs? Is there other function I can use instead of `FullSimplify`?

```
In[12]:= FullSimplify[(-1/2)^(5 n) == (-1/32)^n, 
 Assumptions -> n > 0 && n \[Element] Integers]
Out[12]= True

In[13]:= FullSimplify[(-0.5)^(5 n) == (-1/32)^n, 
 Assumptions -> n > 0 && n \[Element] Integers]
Out[13]= (-0.5)^(5 n) == (-(1/32))^n
```

Comment: as a workaround, wrap the expression inside `FullSimplify`  in `Rationalize`

Comment: Yes, it solves the issue with the sequence (-0.5)^(5n). But, for instance, `geometricSequenceQ[(E/3.1)^(5 n), n]` yields `False`.

Comment: Testing for equality of floating point expression is always going to be problematic. You may need to resort to picking a specific value (or perhaps several) for `n` to test.  Even then you might need to use a tolerance on the equality check.

Comment: Have you thought of using pattern matching? `MatchQ[(E 3.3)^(2 n) , Power[a_?NumericQ, Times[n_?IntegerQ, _]]] (* true *).  It will take a bit of work to get a pattern to match a few cases.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify)/[`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify) don't have a rule to convert $(-0.1)^{5 n}$ to $(-0.00001)^n$ under the assumption that $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. Mathematica does know when it is valid to do so:

```
PowerExpand[(a^5)^n, Assumptions->True]
```

> a^(5 n) E^(2 I n [Pi] Floor[1/2 - (5 Arg[a])/(2 [Pi])])

In particular, for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$:

```
PowerExpand[(a^5)^n, Assumptions->n ∈ Integers]
```

> a^(5 n)

Here is a function that inverts [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand) for certain classes of [`Power`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Power) objects:

```
InversePowerExpand[x_] := Replace[
    x,
    Power[a_Real, n_Integer z_] /; Refine[z ∈ Integers] -> Power[a^n, z]
]
```

Now, we can add this transformation function to [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify)/[`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify):

```
Assuming[
    n ∈ Integers,
    Simplify[(-.1)^(5n), TransformationFunctions->{Automatic, InversePowerExpand}]
]
```

> (-0.00001)^n

I use `Assuming[assum, Simplify[expr]]` instead of the natural `Simplify[expr, assum]` because the [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify) assumptions don't get transferred to the transformation function `InversePowerExpand` automatically.

At any rate, for your question:

```
Assuming[
    n ∈ Integers,
    Simplify[
        (-.5)^(5n) == (-1/32)^n,
        TransformationFunctions->{Automatic, InversePowerExpand}
    ]
]
```

> True

Answer (score 2):

[`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) real numbers in `expr`.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
geometricSequenceQ[expr_, var_] := 
 Module[{a, expr2 = expr /. z_Real :> Rationalize[z, 0]}, 
  a = (expr2 /. var -> #) &;
  If[FullSimplify[a[1]*(a[2]/a[1])^(var - 1) == a[var], 
    Assumptions -> var ∈ Integers && var > 0], True, False]]

geometricSequenceQ[#, n] & /@
 {(-1/2)^(5 n), (-0.5)^(5 n), (E/3.1)^(5 n)}

(*  {True, True, True}  *)
```

Comment: Thank you! This works for all sequences I've tested so far, but I don't think it will leave numeric constants (e.g., Pi, E) as exact: `(-E*0.5)^(5 n) /. z_Real :> Rationalize[z, 0]` results in `(-(148561198/109305221))^(5 n)`, rather than `(-E/2)^(5 n)`. I guess this may cause wrong result for more complex expressions.. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @roman465 - I was mistaken. The division in `(E/3.1)` gets carried out before the rule gets applied. The change in behavior is the increased precision of `Rationalize[#, 0]&` compared to just `Rationalize`

Comment: So I wrapped the expression with `Unevaluated` and set the `HoldFirst` attribute. Now it works just fine! `geometricSequenceQ[expr_, var_] := 
 Module[{a, 
   expr2 = (Unevaluated[expr] /. z_Real :> Rationalize[z, 0])}, 
  a = (expr2 /. var -> #) &;
  If[FullSimplify[a[1]*(a[2]/a[1])^(var - 1) == a[var], 
    Assumptions -> var \[Element] Integers && var > 0], True, False]]
SetAttributes[geometricSequenceQ, HoldFirst]`